# Does orthogonal and zero mean of two RV X,Y imply that they are uncorrelated?

Tags: correlation, random-variable, orthogonal

I understand that two uncorrelated RV X,Y are orthogonal if at least one of both is of zero mean. But can you reverse this statement if you expand the preconditions to *both* RV X,Y being of zero mean?

The problem I solved from an exam says yes it does but I struggle to prove it. Can you help?

Comment: Please tell us your definition of "orthogonal," because it can be applied in different ways in this setting.

Comment: Two RV X,Y are orthogonal if E(XY) = 0

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Where, then, do you run into problems in your proof?  This looks like a straightforward application of any one of the standard formulas for covariance, but perhaps you're starting from something unusual.

Comment: I can't see where the concept of covariance is needed here. Isn't covariance of 0 what we want to proof, not where we want to start?

Comment: "Uncorrelated" is equivalent to a zero covariance.  Recognizing that will simplify your work substantially.

Comment: I know that. And I even know that in this case, the calculation of the covariance is equal to $E(XY)$ which we need to proof is equal to zero because then X,Y are orthogonal. Still cant see how this helps because that is exactly where I started

Answer (score 1):

I am clearly an idiot... Thanks @whuber for making me try it on my own once again.

Given: $X,Y$ are orthogonal $\leftrightarrow E\{X Y\} = 0$

Given: $m_X = 0; m_Y = 0$

$\rightarrow C_{XY} = E\{(X-m_X)(Y-m_Y)\} = E\{XY\} = 0$

$C_{XY} = 0 \leftrightarrow X,Y $ are uncorrelated